# how to pause progressbar in android

Tags: android, android-progressbar, countdowntimer

I have made a progressbar in android,Which is horizontal,i want to freeze it when any button click in my activity,I have tried as below,But progress still displays.my code is as below:I want to do something like one question loaded after another,and onClick of any button counter and progress state should be stop,but  rite now my timer stop but progress still ran up..it not stops.

**code**

```
public class QuestionAnswerActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    // visible gone
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> QuestionList;
    private int progressStatus = 0;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    Intent i;
    private boolean run = true;
    /**
     * Answer [1=true / 0 =false]
     */
    int myans;

    String ans;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    TextView text_player_one;
    String JsonStr;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> questionList;
    ImageView player_one_pic;
    int count;
    private DisplayImageOptions options;
    public static ImageLoader imageLoader;
    ImageView answer_right_one;
    ProgressBar pg_loading;
    private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;

    TextView timer_text;
    private final long startTime = 8 * 1000;
    private final long interval = 1 * 1000;
    Button opt_1, opt_2, opt_3, opt_4;
    Thread splashThread;
    TextView answer_question;
    LinearLayout answer_linear_3;

    // Response variables...!!

    // Single player*************************************

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.question_answer_activity);

        init();

    }

    // ***********************************************************************************************
    /**
     * Initialise the views
     */
    @SuppressWarnings({ "deprecation", "unchecked" })
    private void init() {

        answer_linear_3 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.answer_linear_3);
        answer_linear_3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        questionList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        answer_question = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer_question);

        player_one_pic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.player_one_pic);
        text_player_one = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_player_one);
        text_player_one.setText(Pref.getValue(QuestionAnswerActivity.this,
                Const.PREF_NAME, ""));
        pg_loading = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pg_loading_answer);
        timer_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer_text_loading11);
        answer_right_one = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.answer_right_one);
        imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

        imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration
                .createDefault(QuestionAnswerActivity.this));

        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheOnDisc(true)
                .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer((int) 3.5f))
                .showStubImage(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_launcher).build();
        imageLoader.displayImage(Pref.getValue(QuestionAnswerActivity.this,
                Const.PREF_PROFILE_PIC, ""), player_one_pic, options);

        opt_1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.option_1);
        opt_2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.option_2);
        opt_3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.option_3);
        opt_4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.option_4);
        count = 0;
        questionList = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) getIntent()
                .getSerializableExtra("queList");
        System.out.println("::::::::My questions::::::::;+++++++"
                + questionList);
        /*
         * answer_question.setText(questionList.get(count).get("q_title"));
         * opt_1.setText(questionList.get(count).get("opt1"));
         * opt_2.setText(questionList.get(count).get("opt2"));
         * opt_3.setText(questionList.get(count).get("opt3"));
         * opt_4.setText(questionList.get(count).get("ans"));
         */
        handler.postDelayed(new ViewUpdater(answer_linear_3), 1000);
        answer_question.setText(questionList.get(count).get("q_title"));
        opt_1.setText(questionList.get(count).get("opt1"));
        opt_2.setText(questionList.get(count).get("opt2"));
        opt_3.setText(questionList.get(count).get("opt3"));
        opt_4.setText(questionList.get(count).get("ans"));

        opt_1.setOnClickListener(this);
        opt_2.setOnClickListener(this);
        opt_3.setOnClickListener(this);
        opt_4.setOnClickListener(this);

        countDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(startTime, interval);

        /*
         * Initialise NoResponse Timer
         */
        timer_text.setText(timer_text.getText()
                + String.valueOf(startTime / 1000));

        countDownTimer.start();

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while (progressStatus < 100) {
                    progressStatus += 1;
                    // Update the progress bar and display the

                    // current value in the text view
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            if (run) {
                                pg_loading.setProgress(progressStatus);
                                pg_loading.setProgressDrawable(getResources()
                                        .getDrawable(R.drawable.progress));
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    try {
                        // Sleep for 200 milliseconds.

                        // Just to display the progress slowly
                        Thread.sleep(62);

                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();

    }

    // ***********************************************************************************************

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        run = false;
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.option_1:
            if (count <= 7) {
                count++;
                progressStatus = pg_loading.getProgress();

                /* questionTask(count); */
                new LeaveResponse()
                        .execute(questionList.get(count).get("q_id"));
            }

            break;
        case R.id.option_2:
            if (count <= 7) {
                count++;
                progressStatus = pg_loading.getProgress();
                new LeaveResponse()
                        .execute(questionList.get(count).get("q_id"));
            }

            break;
        case R.id.option_3:
            if (count <= 7) {
                count++;
                progressStatus = pg_loading.getProgress();

                new LeaveResponse()
                        .execute(questionList.get(count).get("q_id"));
            }

            break;
        case R.id.option_4:
            if (count <= 7) {
                count++;
                progressStatus = pg_loading.getProgress();

                new LeaveResponse()
                        .execute(questionList.get(count).get("q_id"));
            }

            /*
             * answer_question.setText(QuestionList.get(count).get("q_title"));
             * opt_1.setText(QuestionList.get(count).get("opt1"));
             * opt_2.setText(QuestionList.get(count).get("opt2"));
             * opt_3.setText(QuestionList.get(count).get("opt3"));
             * opt_4.setText(QuestionList.get(count).get("ans"));
             * timer_text.setText(timer_text.getText() +
             * String.valueOf(startTime / 1000));
             * 
             * countDownTimer.start();
             * answer_right_one.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             * pg_loading.setVisibility(View.GONE); countDownTimer.cancel();
             * 
             * Toast.makeText(QuestionAnswerActivity.this,
             * timer_text.getText().toString(), 1).show();
             */
            break;

        }

    }

    // ***********************************************************************************************
    /**
     * CountDown Timer for Starting No response activity if user doesnt
     * responds.
     */
    public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {
        public MyCountDownTimer(long startTime, long interval) {
            super(startTime, interval);
        }

        public void onpause() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(QuestionAnswerActivity.this, "Clicked", 1).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onFinish",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            /*
             * If finish , that is user not responding , go to NoResponse
             * screen.
             */
            Intent intent = null;
            intent = new Intent(QuestionAnswerActivity.this,
                    NoResponseActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
            startActivity(intent);

            finish();
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            timer_text.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    void questionTask(int count) throws InterruptedException {
        if (count < 8) {

            answer_linear_3.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            answer_question.setText(questionList.get(count).get("q_title"));
            handler.postDelayed(new ViewUpdater(answer_linear_3), 100);
            myans = randomGenerator();
            System.out.println(":::::::::::::;randomized answer::::::::::::;;;"
                    + myans);
            if (myans == 1) {
                opt_1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                        R.drawable.true_selector));
                opt_1.setText(questionList.get(count).get("ans"));
                opt_2.setText(questionList.get(count).get("opt2"));
                opt_3.setText(questionList.get(count).get("opt3"));
                opt_4.setText(questionList.get(count).get("opt1"));

            } else if (myans == 2) {
                opt_2.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                        R.drawable.true_selector));
                opt_1.setText(questionList.get(count).get("opt2"));
                opt_2.setText(questionList.get(count).get("ans"));
                opt_3.setText(questionList.get(count).get("opt3"));
                opt_4.setText(questionList.get(count).get("ans"));

            } else if (myans == 3) {
                opt_3.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                        R.drawable.true_selector));
                opt_1.setText(questionList.get(count).get("opt1"));
                opt_2.setText(questionList.get(count).get("opt2"));
                opt_3.setText(questionList.get(count).get("ans"));
                opt_4.setText(questionList.get(count).get("opt3"));
            } else {
                opt_4.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                        R.drawable.true_selector));
                opt_1.setText(questionList.get(count).get("opt1"));
                opt_2.setText(questionList.get(count).get("opt2"));
                opt_3.setText(questionList.get(count).get("opt3"));
                opt_4.setText(questionList.get(count).get("ans"));
            }

            countDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(startTime, interval);

            /*
             * Initialise NoResponse Timer
             */
            timer_text.setText(timer_text.getText()
                    + String.valueOf(startTime / 1000));

            countDownTimer.start();

        }

    }

    private class ViewUpdater implements Runnable {
        private LinearLayout mView;

        public ViewUpdater(LinearLayout linView) {
            mView = linView;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            mView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    }

    // Answer webservice call..!
    private class LeaveResponse extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();

            countDownTimer.cancel();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(QuestionAnswerActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            BackendAPIService sh = new BackendAPIService();
            String ResponseURL = Const.API_RESPONSE
                    + "?os=droid&user_id="
                    + Pref.getValue(QuestionAnswerActivity.this,
                            Const.PREF_USER_ID, "") + "&myrole="
                    + Const.MY_ROLL + "&q_id=" + params[0] + "&ans=" + ans
                    + "&time=5&game_id=" + Const.GAME_ID + "";
            JsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(ResponseURL, BackendAPIService.GET);
            System.out.println("::::::::::::;My Response request::::::::::;;;"
                    + ResponseURL);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + JsonStr);

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();

            try {
                countDownTimer.cancel();
                pg_loading.setProgress(0);
                progressStatus = 0;
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        while (progressStatus < 100) {
                            progressStatus += 1;
                            // Update the progress bar and display the

                            // current value in the text view
                            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    if (run) {
                                        pg_loading.setProgress(progressStatus);
                                        pg_loading
                                                .setProgressDrawable(getResources()
                                                        .getDrawable(
                                                                R.drawable.progress));
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                            try {
                                // Sleep for 200 milliseconds.

                                // Just to display the progress slowly
                                Thread.sleep(62);

                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }).start();

                questionTask(count);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

    public int randomGenerator() {
        Random r = new Random();
        int ans = r.nextInt(4 - 1) + 1;
        return ans;

    }

}
```

Comment: stop updating  progressBar.setProgress(progress);

Comment: hi..Thanks for response,,But i've already done it.my issue is countdowntimer stops but still my progressbar running to 100%.can you please help me?

Comment: override the onFinish() of timer class

Comment: i am not getting sir,can you give me some code or else ?as it is already override.

Comment: how are you using MyCountDownTimer

Comment: countDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(startTime, interval);

   /*
    * Initialise NoResponse Timer
    */
   timer_text.setText(timer_text.getText()
     + String.valueOf(startTime / 1000));

   countDownTimer.start();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily hold some boolean variable for that case:

```
private boolean run = true;
```

then gather all the Buttons `onClickListeners` in one click listener, like the main one of the class, and upon anyclick make that variable `run=false`, So, check that before set the progress:

```
if(run){
    pg_loading.setProgress(progressStatus);
}else{
    //stop, finish, do whatever you want
}
```

in onClick listener:

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    run = false;
    Intent i;
    switch (v.getId()) {
    .
    .
    .
 }
```

**UPDATE:**

make the thread as the following:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (progressStatus < 100) {
                progressStatus += 1;
                // Update the progress bar and display the

                // current value in the text view
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        if(run){
                           pg_loading.setProgress(progressStatus);
                           pg_loading.setProgressDrawable(getResources()
                                .getDrawable(R.drawable.progress));
                        }
                    }
                });
                try {
                    // Sleep for 200 milliseconds.

                    // Just to display the progress slowly
                    Thread.sleep(62);

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

**UPDATE 2:**
your `onPostExcute` in the `AsyncTask` must be:

```
 @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();

            try {
                countDownTimer.cancel();
                pg_loading.setProgress(0);
                progressStatus = 0;
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        while (progressStatus < 100) {
                            progressStatus += 1;
                            // Update the progress bar and display the

                            // current value in the text view
                            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                        pg_loading.setProgress(progressStatus);
                                        pg_loading
                                                .setProgressDrawable(getResources()
                                                        .getDrawable(
                                                                R.drawable.progress));
                                }
                            });
```

Comment: Sir.Actually i have made like trivia game,in that one by one questions are loaded,so when i click on options of current question my progressbar should be pause at the same time of click,so this way can it be done?i have multiple questions to be loded

Comment: i have added code ,Please review my question sir.waiting for your reply.

Comment: just add it in the first line of your onClick, I'll update my answer for that

Comment: sir,please see my code.its not working i have updated as per suggested..actually my time stops that time but progress ran up...:( please see my updated code.

Comment: do you check the run variable before setting progress ?

Comment: I'm not talking about setProgress in the onClick function only, I'm taking about setProgress in the count down timer

Comment: sir,I have added my whole activity,can you help me by telling where to make change?please sir

Comment: Dude, you are having a thread that will continuously increase the progress bar till 100 without any thing to stop that

Comment: this one `new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while (progressStatus < 100) {` , remove if you don't need or check for `run` value inside it.

Comment: Sir,can you please edit my code?i am really confused..or a piece of code.Please that saves me

Comment: i have wrote it for the first question to be loaded.

Comment: wow..great..its working...thanks sir,but working for only first question only,after that it sticks to that progress only.

Comment: when you want it to begin again you must set `run = true` . What is the case that will makes you want the progress bar to resume, and are you want it then to resume or to begins from 0 ?

Comment: begin from 0 for timer is working,but progress bar sticks at the point where it is last stopped,I want to starts progress bar as well timer from 0.

Comment: well, `setprogress = 0` , and set `run = true`, but I'm asking you where's the point where you want to make the progressbar start again

Comment: Still progress bar not go to 0...!same remains

Comment: So, where is the part on code when you load new question?

Comment: inside OnPostExecute of "LeaveResponse" asynctask.

Comment: first of all, you must set `run=true;` in the beginning of `OnPostExcute`

Comment: or don't check it at all, as you want to force the progress bar to be running in that postExcute method

Comment: can u please update the code...in answer..please sir

Comment: look at **UPDATE2**, also in order to help you the right way, I want you to tell me what's all the wrong cases you face, when the new question shows what exactly happens? but try the new code first